# Angularjs ng-view does not display the Page

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I am new to angularjs,i am working on angularjs Routing using ngRoute.

### MasterPage.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Script/JS/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/JS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/Angular/angular-route.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="Js/app.js"></script>       

</head>
<body ng-app="angualarModule">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
                <a class="brand" style="text-indent: 3em" href="#">
                    Dairy Management
                </a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/Product">Product Master</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Customer Master                    
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#/CustomerMaster">Customer Master</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#/CustomerRate">Customer Rate Master</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Distributer Master                    
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#/DistributerMaster">Distributer Master</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#/DistributerRate">Distributer Rate Master</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class="btn" href="#" style="float:right;">
                    Logout
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

### app.js

```
var angualarModule = angular.module("angualarModule", ['ngRoute']);

angualarModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Product', {
        templateUrl: 'Templates/ProductMaster.html'
    });   

});
```

### ProductMaster.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../Script/JS/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Script/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('HI');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="angualarModule">
    <h1>Product Master</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

- When i click on ProductMaster link the page is not displayed in ng-view.
- There are no errors in console.
- In fact alert('HI') is also getting called which is present in         ProductMaster.html page.

**But ng-view does not display the required page.**

Thanks......

Comment: here's an experiment: keep only  `<h1>Product Master</h1>` in your template and remove all the rest. what happens?

Comment: the view which are going to load by `router` would nothing but partials.. you don't/shouldn't adding `html`, `head`, `body`, etc. tag here

Comment: @AranS Ok i removed everything from my template and kept only <h1>Product Master</h1>,still ng-view does not show the required page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside ProductMaster.html is unnecessary, except `<h1>Product Master</h1>`.

ProductMaster template is just a part of your already included MasterPage.html, and hence having  inside another  would be redundant.

So, your MasterPage.html should only contain `<h1>Product Master</h1>`, not the complete html. And it should work. [Supporting Plunk - http://plnkr.co/edit/hvle5ceu9n4cOVPugbdm?p=preview]

Also, make sure if you're using Bootstrap's JS, your jQ version should be less than 3.

Comment: <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.9" data-semver="1.5.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script> with this version bootstrap does not work properly.The menus do not work as expected as seen in your Plunker sample code.So i think the issue is with version of bootstrap and  Jquery.

Comment: I removed the Jquery version 3.0 and added version 1.8.3,and everything started working fine.ng-view started showing the required page.Thx for the help @Zest.

Answer (score 0):

ProductMaster.html should be only html (not entire page):

```
<h1>Product Master</h1>
```

And to call your JS code use a `controller` in a route object like it described here [$routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

```
 $routeProvider.
        when('/Product', {
            templateUrl: 'Templates/ProductMaster.html',
            controller: 'ProductMasterController', <-- this for JS code
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change these two lines:

```
<script src="Script/Angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="Script/Angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

with these

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

If the routing works, your scripts are missing from `Script/Angular/`.

And don't use the full html page structure (like body and head tags) in partials.

```js
var angualarModule = angular.module("angualarModule", ['ngRoute']);

angualarModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {  
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Product', {
        template: 'ProductMaster.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ 
          redirectTo: '/form' 
    });   

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Script/JS/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Script/JS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>       

</head>
<body ng-app="angualarModule">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container" style="width: auto;">
                <a class="brand" style="text-indent: 3em" href="#">
                    Dairy Management
                </a>
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/Home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/Product">Product Master</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Customer Master                    
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#/CustomerMaster">Customer Master</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#/CustomerRate">Customer Rate Master</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Distributer Master                    
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#/DistributerMaster">Distributer Master</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#/DistributerRate">Distributer Rate Master</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a class="btn" href="#" style="float:right;">
                    Logout
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added CDN files but still no success.

Comment: In My MasterPage.html when F12 is used this is getting loaded <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope"><h1 class="ng-scope">Product Master</h1></div>, So the page is getting called but its not visible.

Comment: For me it works perfectly. Try the code snippet I've inserted.

Comment: I have noticed one thing,if i remove twitter bootstrap from my MasterPage.html and use simple html.Everything works properly then.

Comment: It was Bootstrap and Jquery versioning issue.Thx for the help